# How to find the periphery of an 8 formed by two circles that partially intersect and that are framed in a rectangle?

Tags: java, geometry

Pepe has given himself the task of making a beautiful figure eight, they told him that one way is by drawing two circles that partially intersect and that are framed in a rectangle with base b and height a.

The height is never less than the base and it is never greater than or equal to twice the base. The circles that are drawn are tangent to three sides of the rectangle and are located at opposite ends, as shown in figure 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KveRf.png)

You want to know how much ink should be used to draw the beautiful eight, the amount of ink to use is equivalent to the periphery painted red.

For example: if base (b) is 2 and height (a) is 3, the amount of ink required is 10.109631217141658

Write the method whose signature is:

```
           double inkAmount(int b, int a)
```

that allows calculating the amount of ink required to make the 8 beautiful; given b and a, which are the base and height respectively.

try to solve by finding perimeters of the circles and subtracting the arcs of gray color

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and visit the links on those pages. You are expected to include in your question some code showing your attempt to solve this. Also, the question should include an explanation of where you are stuck, the problem you are having.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Can you, please, provide a link?

Comment: I didn't get the exercise from any link, they gave it to me at the university

Comment: You have to elaborate math solution, calculate angle of common chord and corresponding arc length and chord length to find difference with two circumferences. Then implement this solution in programming language.  If you have problems with YOUR program solution - welcome, ask for specific question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Was this problem given by a professor in a computer programming course? Or did it come from a math professor, and you are trying to use Java to solve it?